# is not equal to the symbols(java)

Tags: java, string, char

Sorry for my English. I want to find out for yourself one point, but I did not get. I want that line of output used in the case of the word. But I have prints like this: if I want to find a word - **one** in line is the application - **ones entered the convent home**. It is still output the line. And in this situation do not want displayed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String line = "line number ones";
    String word = "num";
    String myWord = "";
    int startWord = 0;


    for(int i = 0; i < line.length()-1; i++) {
        if(line.charAt(i) == word.charAt(startWord)) {
            startWord++;
            myWord += line.charAt(i);

            if(myWord.equals(word)) {
                if(startWord == word.length()) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                startWord = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As need to make additional checks. something like:

```
if(Character.toString(line.charAt(i+1)) != any characters except space) {
output line
}
```

Turn out like this:

```
if(startWord == word.length() && Character.toString(line.charAt(i+1)) == " ") {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
```

But it does not work. And we must also take into account that can be a point, a comma, just the end of the line. How to do it?

Comment: How to do what? What input do you give, what output do you expect? What do you mean by *must also take into account that can be a point, a comma, just the end of the line*?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do... But I am sure you can accomplish it with Pattern.match(), Look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm sorry that I express myself clear. I mean, if there is a comma then deduce line. For example: line - **hellow, how are you doing**. word - **hello**. In this case, the line can be displayed. And if line  - **hellow, how are you doing**. word - **doin** . It should not display line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to check if a character is equal to space?If so, you cannot use == on a `String` because it is an object. But you can use it on a `char`.

So two ways are like this:

```
String space = " ";
if (space.equals (" ")) // true
```

Or

```
char space = ' ';
if (space == ' ') // true
```

In your example, you would do this:

```
Character.toString(line.charAt(i+1)).equals (" ")
```